# What is the best Y level for diamonds?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a specific y level for diamonds so that they occur the most? I am having trouble because some people will say Y level 10 or Y level 14 and so on. I just want to know if there is a designated Y level for diamonds or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below level about 15 (12 if you want to be exact) diamonds become more common, however below level 4 they start to get less common. Since the higher the safer in mining, it is recommended to mine about 10 - 12, but if you really want you can go to 6 - 9.

Answer (score 0):

diamonds naturally spawn at level 12. Therefore if you mine at a lower level you will run into more diamonds than if you mine on level 12.

Comment: do we have any proof that it is Y level 12?